# Кириллица и латиница в PostgreSQL при выборке

Tags: sql, postgresql

name_toy    
Lego
Арбуз
Самолет
Кукла

При запросе вывод был таким, я хочу узнать почему первым показало Lego, когда Арбуз должен по логике должен быть на 1 месте.
Идет подсчет что в слове лего 4 буквы или приоритет стоит на английский алфавит?

Comment: Сортировка выполняется согласно кодам символов. Код символа `L` меньше кода символа кириллической `А`. RTFM "collation".

Comment: @Akina спасибо, а где можно посмотреть коды символов?

Comment: Функция `ascii(string)` покажет код первого символа строки.

Comment: @Akina ой отлично, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

> Сортировка выполняется согласно кодам символов

[На самом деле нет](http://unicode.org/faq/collation.html).

> Linguistically meaningful sorting is done not by comparing code point values

В основном сейчас PostgreSQL полагается на методы сортировки предоставляемые системной библиотекой. Для linux систем - это `glibc` обычно, в которой реализованы требования стандарта ISO 14651 `International string ordering and comparison — Method for comparing character strings and description of the common template tailorable ordering`. Этот стандарт иногда меняют и правила сортировки могут немного различаться для разный его версий.

Для других операционных систем необходимо уточнять используемые там правила сортировки. Впрочем, вряд ли встретите что-то отличающееся, правила Unicode довольно повсеместны и это хорошо.

> Идет подсчет что в слове лего 4 буквы или приоритет стоит на английский алфавит?

Сравнение идёт посимвольное независимо от длины строки (именно поэтому если вы сравните строки `1`, `2` и `11` вы получите порядок `1,11,2`), но да, символы латинского алфавита считаются "меньше" символов кириллицы, поэтому по правилам сортировки оказываются в начале.